# How to loop adding elements to vector in Clojure (ArityException)?

Tags: loops, vector, clojure

I need to add new elements to vector, according to the number's value, which is parameter of the function. That means, that if param = 10, so the length of vector should be 10.

The initial vector is [1 1/4], and when we add new element to the vector, we should add 3 to the divisor. So the result should be looking like this:
[1 1/4 1/7 1/9 1/12 1/15 ... etc]

So, here is the code:

```
(defn looper
  [n]
  (loop [array [1 1/4]
         new-div 7]
    (if (< (count array) n)
      (let [r (array)]
        r)
      (recur (conj array (/ 1 new-div))
             (+ new-div 3)))))
```

For me (as I'm a total noob in Clojure), everything seems to be fine, but I always get "ArityException". What's wrong with this piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(let [r (array)]
```

`(f)` means: "call `f` as a function, with no arguments". Your `array` is not a function, but a vector<sup>1</sup>, and you don't want to call it, so just replace `(array)` with `array`.

<sup>1</sup> I know, vectors are functions, but this subtlety is just a distraction to someone who is accidentally calling one.